# How to open Visual Studio's C# program Folder by CMD Command

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Like Html, CSS,JAvaScript or React folder can be open on Visual Studio Code by run command ( code . ).Similarly how can we open our C# program folder in visual studio by cmd command

I'll trying by code . but can't be open Visual studio.

Comment: Run the sln or csproj.

Comment: Did you really want to open the folder not a solution or project?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. "Visual Studio" and "Visual Studio Code" are different products. What do you mean by "program folder? "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE"?

Comment: Open a cmd window and type: `explorer %UserProfile%\Documents` to see if this is the desired result. If so, type: `explorer <fully-quallified-path to desired folder>` In C#, one could use [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-7.0).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Windows `start` command:

```
start MySolution.sln
```

This will open the program registered for `*.sln` files which normally is Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: Go to Control Panel -> System and Security -> System. Under Advanced System Setting option click on Environment Variables as shown below:

[image]

[image]

**Step 2**: Now, we have to alter the “Path” variable under System variables so that it also contains the path to the .NET Framework environment. Select the “Path” variable and click on the Edit button as shown below:

[image]

**Step 3**: We will see a list of different paths, click on the New button and then add the path where .NET Framework is installed.( If not installed, you need to install it yourself)

[image]

**Step 4**: Click on OK, Save the settings and it is done !! Now to check whether the environment setup is done correctly, open command prompt and type csc.

[image]

**Step 5**: Open the text editor like Notepad or Notepad++, and write the code that you want to execute. Now save the file with .cs extension.

[image]

**Step 6**: Compile your C# source code with the use of command:

csc File_name.cs

If your program has no error then it will create a filename.exe file in the same directory where you have saved your program. Suppose you saved the above program as Hello.cs. So you will write csc Hello.cs on cmd. This will create a Hello.exe file.

[image]

**Step 7**: Now there are two ways to execute the Hello.exe. First, you have to simply type the filename i.e Hello on the cmd and it will give the output. Second, you can go to the directory where you saved your program and there you find filename.exe. You have to simply double-click that file and it will give the output.

Using Command:

[image]

Using .exe file:

[image]